# Notepad ++ Replace/Remove number

Tags: notepad++

How can i replace or remove behind the second (.) ip's

`46.184.59.75
220.188.46.70
159.20.136.240`

I want to look like this :

`46.184.0.0
220.188.0.0
159.20.0.0`

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a Regex replace.

On the normal Search -> Replace dialog (<kbd>CTRl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> in Windows), set the Search Mode to Regular Expression, then set this as the Find:

```
(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}
```

and this as the replace

```
\1\.0\.0
```

This matches text with the format `<number>.<number>.<number>.<number>` stores the first two sets as the first match, hence the (parantheses), then replaces it with the first match (`\1`) followed by `.0.0`. As `.` is a special character in regular expressions, you need to escape it with a `\` in both the find and the replace.